# Programatically export sensitive information type matches from the Mcirosoft Purview portal

Tags: microsoft365, o365security-compliance

In the Microsoft purview portal, https://compliance.microsoft.com/dataclassification/contentexplorer, I can see the individual sensitive information types displayed in the UI and I can drill down and find the individual document where the sensitive information is found.

[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible and if so how, with the right permissions, to programmatically, PowerShell, c# etc., to extract this information?